# css3 nth-child specificity

Tags: css, css-selectors, css-specificity

How come these two don't come out equivalent? The first one shows a green row, while the second doesn't. The only difference is in html c Furthermore, what is the specificity of the nth-child selector?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Stripe Test</title>
        <style type='text/css'>
            tr:nth-child(2n+1)
            {
                background-color: red;
            }
            tr.c
            {
                background-color: green;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <table class='stripe'>
            <tr class='c'>
                <td>one</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>two</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>three</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

-vs-

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Stripe Test</title>
        <style type='text/css'>
            tr:nth-child(2n+1)
            {
                background-color: red;
            }
            tr .c
            {
                background-color: green;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <table class='stripe'>
            <tr class='c'>
                <td>one</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>two</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>three</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Regarding the specificity, see [the specs](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#specificity); `nth-child` is a pseudo-class, so perform the specificity calculation appropriately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`tr.c` (no space)` is a table row of class c.

`tr .c` (with space) is a table row, followed by some OTHER unspecified tag with class c.

The space implies a parent/child relationship. Since you've got the `c` class **ON** the tr tag itself, there is no child below the `tr` that has a `c` class.

Answer (score 2):

The second one is a completely different selector. `tr .c` with a space in between looks for an element with class name "c" that has an ancestor `<tr>` element. The first one `tr.c` looks for a `<tr>` element that has the class name "c".

This has nothing to do with specificity, but instead your understanding of CSS.

Answer (score -1):

Consider using :nth-child(odd) instead, and also note IE does not like it at all.

Comment: There is no difference between `:nth-child(odd)` and `:nth-child(2n+1)`.